# Multiply two list objects with same name

Tags: r, list

Similar questions have been raised for **all** combinations of objects within lists (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552387/multiplying-combinations-of-a-list-of-lists-in-r) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378143/multiply-two-list-objects-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)), but this particular problem has yet not been asked:

I have two lists that contain the same (high) number of data frames, with the same name, size and ordering, though different values, see this sample data set:

```
A <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(30), nrow=5, ncol=6))
B <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=5, ncol=4))
list1 <- list(A,B)

A <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(30), nrow=5, ncol=6))
B <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=5, ncol=4))
list2 <- list(A,B)
```

I would now like to multiply data frames with the same name element wise and store the result in a new list, such that:

```
list3: 
A*A B*B
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just `Map('*', list1, list2)`

Comment: Thanks, this works. The question has indeed been [anwered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25233916/r-multiply-matrixes-in-list) as marked by Imo. However, as title and question of the latter are somewhat blurry / misleading I will leave my question in the system for future reference !?

Comment: Yes leave it up. It serves as a reference point